# Best way to cure slimelung?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have read all the precautions to prevent Dupes get sick with slimelung.

But what is the best (easiest, fastest) way to cure a Dupe from slimelung?
What I have done so far:

- Created a Medbay
- Removed all jobs for the contaminated Dupe (to prevent 'runaway patient')
- Set the medical bed to highest priority

What I don't understand:
How can I force another Dupe to faster spend medical care? Or to dose some pills like the new 'Vitamin Pill' or Placebo Pill?

Sometimes I can see that the illness even get worser and take longer then the moment before. What can be the cause for this?

Answer (score 3):

Removing all jobs and assigning them a med-bed (or pharma chamber) is the best you can do.  In the new Occupational update, make sure you mark them as "unemployed", and toggle their options off in the separate Jobs tab as well.  Additionally, make sure another duplicant has "Care" enabled as a job.